# Could not load file or assembly 'WebDriver, Version=2.35.0.0 ...'

Tags: visual-studio-2012, selenium, selenium-webdriver, coded-ui-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I followed steps of "[Selenium components for Coded UI Cross Browser Testing](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/11cfc881-f8c9-4f96-b303-a2780156628d)".

But I had download the lastest version of:

WebDriver.ChromeDriver.win32 2.4.0
http://www.nuget.org/packages/WebDriver.ChromeDriver.win32/

selenium-dotnet-strongnamed-2.37.0
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list

then I installed those in my machine of 64bits but the Visual Studio 2013 present the next problem when I try to run automated test:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
'WebDriver, Version=2.35.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1c2bd1631853048f' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
    To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
    Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
    To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into the main problem with using strong-named (so-called "signed") assemblies as references. The Microsoft cross-browser tools are bound to a reference to a **specific** version of the Selenium .NET bindings. In this case, the version of the cross-browser tools directly reference 2.35.0 of the .NET bindings. No other version will do; you'll have to download **specifically** [that version](http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-dotnet-strongnamed-2.35.0.zip) of the .NET bindings.

Comment: Could you please further I really get what I need to do.

Comment: Ten years later still the same problem — only the download link doesn't work.