# VS 2013 - Unable to run Coded UI test in Firefox browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I had version of:

```
Visual Studio 2013  

WebDriver.ChromeDriver.win32 2.2.0 

selenium-dotnet-strongnamed-2.35.0  

Firefox 24
```

But when I run Coded UI test I had received the next error:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestException:
>   Failed to start up socket within 45000 ms

or the next error:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestException: An
>   error occurred while connecting to Firefox

I folowed instructions of here: [Selenium components for Coded UI Cross Browser Testing](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/11cfc881-f8c9-4f96-b303-a2780156628d)

Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things: update Selenium to v2.37 (v2.35 doesn't support Firefox 24) and don't use the strong-named assemblies unless you have to.

I mean, really, have to.

They create more problems then they are worth.

Comment: In the past I had updated Selenium to v2.37 but I had had the next problem describe here: [Could not load file or assembly 'WebDriver, Version=2.35.0.0 …'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521891/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-webdriver-version-2-35-0-0)

Comment: @kuskunko, then you are stuck. You will have to downgrade Firefox and pester Microsoft to not reference a specific version of Selenium. Since you can't upgrade them, you will have to downgrade. Probably to Firefox 22.

Comment: Arran thanks for your help, maybe I will wait for new versions.